# www 301 redirection on WordPress uploads folder not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

An analysis of our WordPress website has discovered that any image/PDF uploaded to WordPress and access directly do not redirect to the www version. This also happens with the robots.txt file.

We have an .htaccess file that is currently working for the pages on the page. So, if I type:
https://mywebsite.com

I will be redirected to
https://www.mywebsite.com

I have made sure that all links to the PDFs and images are properly setup for the www version.

As a test, I attempted to setup an .htaccess file on the uploads folder of WordPress and setup a redirect there, but it did not work.

Is there any way to setup a redirect for files/images placed on the uploads folder of WordPress?

An example of URL would be: https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/myfile.pdf

My current redirection rule on the .htaccess file is as follows:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: There is no direct reason why this should _not_ also work for the uploads folder. Please show this in context, where this is located within the rest of the URL rewriting WP does.

Comment: The redirection rule is set at the root level, coexisting with the default WordPress folders (wp-admin, wp-content, etc).. The redirection does indeed apply on standard website URLs (example: homepage redirection from non WWW to WWW version works fine). However, for the uploads folder contained within wp-content and all the recurring folders (2022, 2023...) that are created when a file or image is uploaded on WordPress, the redirection does not happen.